# Apollo 11 throttle telemetry: what is this value?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-11

I cannot find any clue in [AGC SW](https://github.com/virtualagc/virtualagc/) about the value in last column of pages 15-23 of ["Apollo 11 LM-5 computer words" document](http://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/apollo_11_computer_words.pdf):

[image: screenshot]

I think it reads:

```
CMDECA
THRT OUTPUT
COUNTER
```

But I cannot find any reference to this "CMDECA" string. CMD-ECA? (Command-ECA) CM-DECA? (Command Module DECA).

According to other columns, it should be "short string" for "THRT OUTPUT COUNTER", but I can't find anyway any clue.

Assuming it is throttle output of main descent engine, it's ok as long as it's = 11059.2 (=100%) during first part of the descent, but once engine is turned off at 102:39:29 (as confirmed by Aldrin and Armstrong, see transcript below), what does it happen to it? Why does it oscillate that way? It appears out of control, but it should be just off, or maybe at fixed throttle 10% (=1105.0).

- 102:39:34 Aldrin: Wow! Throttle down...
- 102:39:35 Armstrong: Throttle down on time.
- 102:39:36 Duke: Roger. We copy throttle down...
- 102:39:38 Aldrin: You can feel it in here when it throttles down. Better than the (stationary) simulator.

My related question about overall decoding of the mentioned document is [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/192036?noredirect=1), while progress on my decoding work is [here](https://github.com/jumpjack/dskysim/wiki/Decoding-AGC-telemetries).

Comment: ECA is probably Engine Control Assembly. Thus Command-EngineControlAssembly.

Comment: any idea about why it floats?

Comment: to me it looks like a bit of signal processing; something went from 11000 to 0 and the signal shows a small, transient overshoot to -500 followed by a quick exponential decay back to 0, plus a little noise and offset. What does it look like if you plot it?

Comment: to plot it I will have to manually type some hundreds of values.... I would like to understand if I would get one of these charts, or if it's something else: https://github.com/jumpjack/Apollo11LEMdata/blob/master/006-throttle_overall-01.png   , https://github.com/jumpjack/Apollo11LEMdata/blob/master/005-throttle-01.png

Comment: Oh, I was just looking at the numbers indicated with the big red box in the question.